# Bitbake binary file not found

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using bitbake to build and deploy my application to my linux build. I was recently made aware that my binary application was not being deployed to `/usr/bin`. I was told to update my mainapplication.bb to have the following line. `install -m 0644 ${S}/MAIN_Application ${D}${bindir}`

Doing do causes my bitbake build to crash as it cannot find the `MAIN_Application` binary file.

My full bitbake file is as follows

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://MAIN_Application \
        file://services \   
    "

inherit autotools systemd

S = "${WORKDIR}/MAIN_Application"

DEPENDS += "libsocketcan"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "MAINapplication.service"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/services/MAINapplication.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/MAINapplication.service
    install -m 0644 ${S}/MAIN_Application ${D}${bindir}
}
```

I am using autotools, I have a makefile.am, configure.ac and autogen script. Running them locally I get the appropriate binary file which I can place onto the device and run. I am wondering why bitbake cannot find the binary file in its automated process.

Edit: The binary file is created and stored at `build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/mainapplication/0.0-r0/build`. Is my path incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autotools` compiles into build folder which is `${B}`

Just confirm that that is your build directory:

```
bitbake -e mainapplication | grep ^B=
```

and change this line:

```
install -m 0644 ${S}/MAIN_Application ${D}${bindir}
```

by this line:

```
install -m 0644 ${B}/MAIN_Application ${D}${bindir}
```

Comment: Last comment, this did work but when spawning the process it failed with a Permission Denied error. Is there a command to run before this to give permissions?

Comment: You got `Permission Denied` on the board? If yes, try to change the permissions on the board with `chmod`, then take the correct permissions and change them in place of `0644` in the recipe.

Comment: Yes running ssytemctl status mainapplication. I attempted to EXEC but ran into a permission denied error

Comment: Are you adding a custom user (other than root) ?

Comment: I did get it working. Ideally yes a custom user will be added